# Need advice for dynamic update table value (C#, MVC3, JavaScript)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, dynamic-data

I have html page with table on it. Simplify it may look at:

```
<Row_ID>, <bla-bla-bla>, <_XXX.XX%_ is complete>
```

In C# I has a function that evaluate "% is complete" by ID. But it operation may take some times (not instant and may cause some delay )

Now I need implement auto-refresh of "% is complete" that will be update data in one or two minutes interval. I do not want to reload neither entire page nor entire table (if I do it by ajax). Because user may look at the page and the reloading will brake its current position (or even rows counts in the table).

So I think about javascript setTimeout that call some function and to get values from server (by JSON?) But I'm not sure about web-page freeze when javascript function will request data. May be there are another update methods exists?

Any versions or suggestions are welcome!

Sorry for my broken English.

Comment: The ajax request won't freeze the page. "A" for asynchronous... I'd go for your strategy and measure the results.

Comment: I thought about it. So this would work : 1. function called from setTimeout (or setInterval) and inside it call $.ajax(... SomeFunc2 ..). Has it launch SomeFunc2 in "parallel" therad?

Comment: Or I see... SomeFunc2 will work in the same thread, but only call will be asynchronous. I need to test it... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should accomplish what you mean.  I am assuming you will make a single call to return a JSON result of multiple results (most efficient).  Also, jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls are asynchronous, so there will be no page 'freeze' - also, just guessing at your MVC Model setup, but I think you get the idea?

```
<table>
    @foreach(var line in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@line.Id</td>
        <td>@line.Something</td>
        <td id="p-@line.Id">@line.Percentage% complete</td>                   
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

JS:

```
var to;
$().ready(function() {
    ResetUpdate();
});

function Update() {
    // do your $.ajax();
    // if success,
    // assuming return data is an array like:
    var data = [ {id:1, p:26}, {id:2, p:99} ];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#p-' + data[i].id).html(data[i].p + '% complete');            
    }
    ResetUpdate();
}

function ResetUpdate() {
    to = setTimeout("Update()", 120000); //2 minutes
}
```

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgaSA/3/).